# --mount volume command been recognized as command line arguments of container

Tags: docker

I try to mount a volume to my container when creating it, but the '--mount' command was recognized as the arguments of my container.

i have tried many ways, like using '' or ; at the end of real arguments, but none of them worked

docker run -d --name twitter_crawler twitter_crawler:1.0 -n 3 --mount source=myvol2,target=/app nginx:latest

"-n 3" is the real arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `docker run` command requires all options to precede the image name.  For example:

```
docker run -d \
  --name twitter_crawler \
  --mount source=myvol2,target=/app \
  twitter_crawler:1.0 -n 3
```